# magento attributes on back end

Tags: magento

Hey guys
I have a problem, that is I have a d.o.b attribute
displayed on the front-end but the info that gets written
by the customer, I don't get on the back-end or the magento dashboard
can I please get help on how to get the d.o.b info on the back-end customer info
please help.....

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Magento 1.5, there is a Date of Birth attribute for the Customer entity. This attribute is on the Account Information section of the Customer Information tab in the admin. I'm not sure if this is the case prior to 1.5 as I currently don't have access to an earlier install. But this attribute is not available for entry on the front end (in customer/account/create/ or customer/account/edit/)  in the latest or previous versions.

Which leads me to believe that you're using a pre 1.5 version of Magento and that you or someone you know may have modified a core design template to add that field to the front end. If this is the case, then that field needs to be an actual attribute of the Customer entity. Once it is so, you can rewrite the content block for the Account Information section of the Customer Information tab to a block in a new module of yours to display that field.